# display ajax data in django view

Tags: django, jquery, django-views

I get some form values by ajax and post them to preview page. but I couldn't get how to reach those values in my template file. here are my codes:

my ajax function:

```
$('#preview').click(function() {

        var title = $('#id_title').val(); // form input1
        var body = $('#id_body').val(); // forminput2

     var ajaxOptions = {
         type:'post',
         url : '/admin/post/preview/',//preview page's url which defined in urls.py
         data : {
             'title_preview' : title,
             'body_preview'  : body
         },
         success: function(){
             window.open("/admin/post/preview"); // to see preview of post in a new window
         },
         error: function(){
            alert('olmadı');
         }
     };


        $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
```

my view:

```
@require_POST
def preview(request):

    title_preview = request.POST.get('title_preview')
    body_preview = request.POST.get('body_preview')
    query = Post(titlePreview = title_preview,bodyPreview = body_preview,owner = request.user)
    query.save()

    return render_to_response('preview.html',{'post':query},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

but it doesn't work. it seems blank page.I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Did you try to print the "title_preview" & "body_preview" just before the POST() object? How do you access the "post" in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're posting to your preview view, then when that returns successfully you are trying to open a separate window by calling the same URL again. But the second call doesn't have any POST data, so naturally it won't work. Your `success` function should do something with the data it's already being passed, rather than trying to open a new URL.

Comment: @alix Did you found the solution for this?